# awk how to find only in column 2 empty cell and replace with text

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

I have the following input

```
server01, 
server02, 
server03, 
server04, windows 2008 R2 USA
server05, Linux Centos Canada
server06, 
server07, 
server08, Linux RedHat UK
server09, 
server10, 
...
```

I need command to replace only the lines that have nothing in column 2 with text to get the following output:

```
server01, Incomplete
server02, Incomplete
server03, Incomplete
server04, windows 2008 R2 USA
server05, Linux Centos Canada
server06, Incomplete
server07, Incomplete
server08, Linux RedHat UK
server09, Incomplete
server10, Incomplete
...
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You did accept a none working answer.

Comment: You have in your post a single space after `serverxx,`.  It may create problem for several solution here, if that is missing. So make sure there are space in all your data, or select a solution not depending on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
awk '{if (!$2) {print $1, "Incomplete"} else {print $1, $2}}' myfile.txt
```

Output:

```
server01, Incomplete
server02, Incomplete
server03, Incomplete
server04, windows 2008 R2 USA
server05, Linux Centos Canada
server06, Incomplete
server07, Incomplete
server08, Linux RedHat UK
server09, Incomplete
server10, Incomplete
```

Comment: With GNU awk: `awk -F',' 'OFS="," {if ($2==" ") {print $1, " Incomplete"} else {print $1, $2}}' filename`

Comment: Thanks guys this is working as expected. I will accept this anwser as the awk was mentioned in the question many thanks for your help

Comment: You miss a  `-` in front of the  `F`. Even then it does not work. You need to remove the field separator. It should be some like this (shorten some): `awk '{if (!$2) print $1, "Incomplete"; else print $1, $2}' file` or shorten even more, like my second example in my post.

Comment: @Jotne thanks have modified and added - in front of F.

Comment: Since all lines do have one `,` it will all have two fields, and your solution does not work. You need to remove the  `-F','`.    `awk -F',' '{print NF}'` file, give s `2 2 2 2 2 2 ....`.  But this `awk '{print NF}' file` gives  `1 1 1 5 4 1 1 ...`

Comment: It does not work with the OPs data. You are using a field separator that gives `2` field for every line.  It will only remove the `,` from the data.  I have edited your post to show actual output of your command.  Please remove it, when you have read it. (not possible to post in comment.)

Comment: That is why I always post output of all my command, if they are not to long to post....

Comment: This will fail if $2 is populated but has numeric value zero, puts the condition inside the action block where it doesn't belong, uses negative logic instead of positive, redundantly repeats `print $1` will truncate existing $2 values to the first substring before a space, and will fail if $1 contains a space.

Comment: Sorry guys. Im looking for the same output but instead of 2 columns I got 5. How to edit the above command in order to obtain the same in a 5 column file? I tried somethin like awk '{if (!$2,$3,$4,$5) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5, "Incomplete"} else {print $1, $2,$3,$4,$5}}'  myfile.txt but doesnt work

Comment: What's your input and what's the output you expect?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this sed command

```
sed 's/, $/&Incomplete/' FileName
```

there is  no space after server01, try `*` zero or more occurrence

```
sed 's/, *$/&Incomplete/'
```

**Output :**

```
server01, Incomplete
server02, Incomplete
server03, Incomplete
server04, windows 2008 R2 USA
server05, Linux Centos Canada
server06, Incomplete
server07, Incomplete
server08, Linux RedHat UK
server09, Incomplete
server10, Incomplete
```

Comment: A small variation: `sed 's/, $/&Incomplete/' filename`

Comment: @Cyrus,Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Why `'/, $/s/, $/&Incomplete/'` instead of simply `'s/, $/&Incomplete/'` as @Cyrus suggested?

Answer (score 2):

With bash:

```
while IFS=, read -r A B; do echo -n "$A,"; [[ $B == " " ]] && echo " Incomplete" || echo "$B"; done
```

Output:

```
server01, Incomplete
server02, Incomplete
server03, Incomplete
server04, windows 2008 R2 USA
server05, Linux Centos Canada
server06, Incomplete
server07, Incomplete
server08, Linux RedHat UK
server09, Incomplete
server10, Incomplete
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk 'NF==1{$0=$0"incomplete"}1' file
server01, incomplete
server02, incomplete
server03, incomplete
server04, windows 2008 R2 USA
server05, Linux Centos Canada
server06, incomplete
server07, incomplete
server08, Linux RedHat UK
server09, incomplete
server10, incomplete
```

If its only one field, add extra text.

---

Here is an other variation:

```
awk '!$2{print $1,"Incomplete";next}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:

```
awk -F, '{print $0 ($2=="" ? "Incomplete" : "")}' file
```

All other currently posted awk solutions will fail given some specific values of $1 and/or $2 (e.g. if $2 has the numeric value zero or $1 contains a space or ...).

Comment: Thanks Ed but i get error with your command

$ awk -F', ' {print $0 ($2=="" ? "Incomplete" : "")}' test
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: It had an extra `'` at the front. fixed now. Surprised you didn't spot that yourself though.